# How does the copy constructor work when a function passes a parameter by value?

Tags: c++, function, constructor, copy, this

I've been working on a linked list and have a function `CountListItems()` that passes the list by value. A copy is to be made and the copy constructor is invoked.

The copy constructor crashes when it attempts to make a copy. I'm confused, what does `this` point to in the copy constructor? There is no calling object in this case, right?

When I run the debugger, `this` has the same number of nodes as the parameter but all of its values are uninitialized.

Any attempt to delete the nodes of `this` causes a crash. Line (1) at the bottom in the copy constructor is my current solution. Does this cause a memory leak even though the program works?

```
//main.cpp

int CountListItems(LinkedList data);

int main ()
{
    LinkedList list;
    int x = 1;
    list.InsertData(x);

    /* Pass LinkedList by value, so that the copy constructor is invoked. */
    CountListItems(data);

    return 0;
}
```

---

```
//LinkedList.h

class LinkedList
{
public:
    struct Node
    {
        int data;
        Node *prev;
        Node *next;
    }

    /* Copy constructor */
    LinkedList(LinkedList &original);
    ~LinkedList();
    DataInsert(int data);

private:
    /* Copy list node by node. */
    void CopyList(LinkedList &original);
    Node *first;
    Node *curr;
    Node *last;

};
```

---

```
//LinkedList.cpp

/* Copy Constructor */
LinkedList::LinkedList(LinkedList &original)
{
    first = last = curr = 0;       // (1) Attempt at a solution (Initialize "this")
    /* this->~LinkedList(); */     // (2) Produces Crash
    CopyList(original);            // (3) Without (1) Produces Crash

    return;
}
```

Comment: Note: you're missing a semi-colon after the declaration of the `Node` subclass in `LinkedList`. And `DataInsert` has no return type, which is required for standard-compliant C++. You should fix *both*, or post *real code*.

Answer (score 1):

1. You have just declared the `destructor` like `~LinkedList();`. Ideally you should define it too and should write some `delete` code in there to free some memory. Or leave de definition blank as `~LinkedList() { }`. This is why (2) produces crash.
2. You should have a `default constructor` or some other way to initialize the pointers. Missing this step would generate an exception in case the pointers are used without initializing.
3. As already mentioned in a comment by WhozCraig, the `struct` definition should end with a `;` - semi-colon.
4. You are calling `InsertData()` and the function in your class reads `DataInsert()`. Is this a typo?